# The last $\omega$ -many things in any cardinal?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Is it possible to do this?  For instance, could I take the last $\omega$-many things in $\omega_1$? Maybe you could just invert the well ordering and select that way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. You cannot.

Every countable set of countable ordinals is bounded way way way below $\omega_1$. In fact, if $\alpha_n$ is a countable sequence of countable ordinals then $\omega_1\setminus\sup\{\alpha_n\mid n\in\omega\}$ has cardinality $\aleph_1$.

In particular there are no "last $\omega$ elements of $\omega_1$".

This is about cardinality, if you mean order type, that is choosing an end-segment which has order type $\omega$, then you don't need to go as far as $\omega_1$ to have an ordinal which doesn't have a tail segment of order type $\omega$. It is enough to go as far as $\omega^2$ to have this.

The reason is that an ordinal has a tail segment of order type $\omega$ if and only if it can be written as $\gamma+\omega$. Clearly $\omega^2$ cannot be written like that, and neither can be $\omega_1$.